# Is SQL "inherently transactional"?

Tags: database, transactions

I just read in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), that SQL is inherently transactional.
I took this to mean that every statement made to a SQL DBMS is treated as a transaction by default. Is this correct?

An example I can think of that might make this question relevant would be if you considered an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Employee SET salary=salary * 1.1 WHERE type='clerk';
```

If this were being processed and there was some failure that caused the DBMS to shutdown, on restart, in a transactional sense, wouldn't the rows that records that were updated be rolled back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a breaking point when a database transaction will get corrupted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533989/is-there-a-breaking-point-when-a-database-transaction-will-get-corrupted)

Comment: From the linked answer: The rdbms writes data first to a transaction log before actually updating the data. After a crash, it replays the log, copying any pending changes from the log into the database, and rolling back any transactions which have not been completed in the log. Commit is reported as successful only after the hard disk has reported a completed write operation to the log.

Comment: That answer seems on point, but closing this question doesn't make sense. Two different questions can have the same answer. Also, the example I used is just to provide clarity on the question, which is not yet answered.

Comment: "If this were being processed and there was some failure that caused the DBMS to shutdown, on restart, in a transactional sense, wouldn't the rows that records that were updated be rolled back?" sounds very similar to me. Can you expand on how it's different?

Comment: Well, I'm really asking if generally SQL databases are transactional. The answerer starts by saying "If the database system is carefully written..."  and then shares how the transaction logs can come into play in such a system. Is it that, because of his answer, one can say, SQL is inherently transactional?

Answer (score 0):

At least in SQL Server, if you run a transaction, opening the line with

```
BEGIN TRAN
```

and you don't commit or rollback the transaction, it will ask you (if you try to exit the window) if you want to commit the transactions.  If something caused everything to crash, and we had an open transaction (meaning, nothing to close it), it would *not* be considered committed.

Your question demonstrates another reason why many developers will use a `COMMIT TRAN` only if there are no errors, so every transaction by default, will rollback.

Disclaimer here: I am ***ONLY*** referring to SQL Server - I cannot say this would hold true for other SQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. SQL is a language, what you describe is ACID behaviour. Though many database systems behave that way, it is still perfectly possible to create one that uses SQL as language and allows statements to be partially executed.